# Find width of element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is embarrassing. Why is my code not working below??

```
<div id="wotcha" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:blue;"></div>

var width = $("#wotcha").width();
alert(width);
```

JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/adv1jem6/

Thanks!

Comment: Check web dev tools `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`

Comment: you need to import jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jxuu1aw6/

Comment: add jquery.js to your code

Comment: I must be being incredibly thick - I've never had to do that before - I just select jQuery 3.2.1 and it works.. How am I MEANT to add jQuery then?? Sorry - I always use jsfiddle, and I've never had this issue before...

Comment: Seems like a jsFiddle problem with jQuery 3.2.1 only. Change it to any other version and it's fine.

Comment: it looks like an issue with jsfiddle and/or jquery 3.2.1 since selecting v3.1.1 works fine

Comment: You're right - thank you. Sorry - didn't expect jsfiddle to be broken like that, so assumed it had to be me!

Comment: The creator of jsFiddle is http://stackoverflow.com/users/199748/oskar-krawczyk but he hasn't been active since last 2015. Probably best to ping him on Twitter

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you included `jQuery` in the `<head>` Tag via e.g. a cdn

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also make sure that the dom is loaded with `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $("#wotcha").width();
    alert(width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems jquery.js file is not loading or not available.

Comment: This is actually the closest correct answer: jQuery 3.2.1 was broken on jsfiddle.